# Why am I getting undefined method error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When I post, I get this error.

> undefined method `community_community_topic_url'

My codes are

**show.html.erb**

```
<%- model_class = @community_topic.class -%>
<div class="page-header">
  <h1><%=t '.title', :default => model_class.model_name.human %></h1>
</div>

<dl class="dl-horizontal">
  <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:community_id) %>:</strong></dt>
  <dd><%= @community_topic.community_id %></dd>
  <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:user_id) %>:</strong></dt>
  <dd><%= @community_topic.user_id %></dd>
  <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:title) %>:</strong></dt>
  <dd><%= @community_topic.title %></dd>
  <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:body) %>:</strong></dt>
  <dd><%= @community_topic.body %></dd>
  <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:community_topic_icon_file_name) %>:</strong></dt>
  <dd><%= @community_topic.community_topic_icon_file_name %></dd>
  <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:community_topic_icon_content_type) %>:</strong></dt>
  <dd><%= @community_topic.community_topic_icon_content_type %></dd>
  <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:community_topic_icon_file_size) %>:</strong></dt>
  <dd><%= @community_topic.community_topic_icon_file_size %></dd>
  <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:community_topic_icon_updated_at) %>:</strong></dt>
  <dd><%= @community_topic.community_topic_icon_updated_at %></dd>
  <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:deleted_at) %>:</strong></dt>
  <dd><%= @community_topic.deleted_at %></dd>
</dl>

<div class="form-actions">
  <%= link_to t('.back', :default => t("helpers.links.back")),
              community_topics_path, :class => 'btn'  %>
  <%= link_to t('.edit', :default => t("helpers.links.edit")),
              edit_community_topic_path(@community_topic), :class => 'btn' %>
  <%= link_to t('.destroy', :default => t("helpers.links.destroy")),
              community_topic_path(@community_topic),
              :method => 'delete',
              :confirm => t('.confirm', :default => t("helpers.links.confirm", :default => 'Are you sure?')),
              :class => 'btn btn-danger' %>
</div>
```

**community_topics_controller.rb**

```
def create
@community = Community.find_by_community_name(params[:community_id]) 


@community_topic = @community.community_topics.build (params[:id]) 

    respond_to do |format|
      if @community_topic.save
        format.html { redirect_to [@community, @community_topic], notice: 'Community topic was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: [@community, @community_topic], status: :created, location: @community_topic }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @community_topic.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :communities, :path => "shop", do
    resources :community_topics, :path => "topic", :as => :'topic'
end
```

**Result of Rake routes**

```
community_topic_index GET    /shop/:community_id/topic(.:format)          community_topics#index
                         POST   /shop/:community_id/topic(.:format)          community_topics#create
     new_community_topic GET    /shop/:community_id/topic/new(.:format)      community_topics#new
    edit_community_topic GET    /shop/:community_id/topic/:id/edit(.:format) community_topics#edit
         community_topic GET    /shop/:community_id/topic/:id(.:format)      community_topics#show
                         PUT    /shop/:community_id/topic/:id(.:format)      community_topics#update
                         DELETE /shop/:community_id/topic/:id(.:format)      community_topics#destroy
```

UPDATE:

The error I get

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"community_topics"}
```

**development.log**

```
Processing by CommunityTopicsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"pc24BKJrqOaXxZHlRWEPQJKfvdcG9xVM98IqbJW4KgY=", "community_topic"=>{"community_id"=>"4", "user_id"=>"2", "title"=>"topic_title1", "body"=>"topic_body1"}, "commit"=>"Save Community topic", "community_id"=>"WALMART"}
  [1m[35mCommunity Load (0.5ms)[0m  SELECT `communities`.* FROM `communities` WHERE `communities`.`community_name` = 'smabrox' AND (`communities`.`deleted_at` IS NULL) LIMIT 1
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.8ms)[0m  INSERT INTO `community_topics` (`body`, `community_id`, `community_topic_icon_content_type`, `community_topic_icon_file_name`, `community_topic_icon_file_size`, `community_topic_icon_updated_at`, `created_at`, `deleted_at`, `title`, `updated_at`, `user_id`) VALUES (NULL, 4, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2012-12-24 05:52:37', NULL, NULL, '2012-12-24 05:52:37', NULL)
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
  [1m[36m (4.1ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 46ms

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"community_topics"}):
  app/controllers/community_topics_controller.rb:56:in `block (2 levels) in create'
  app/controllers/community_topics_controller.rb:54:in `create'
```

**community_topics_controller.rb**

```
  def create
    @community = Community.find_by_community_name(params[:community_id]) 
    @community_topic = @community.community_topics.build (params[:id]) 

    respond_to do |format|
      if @community_topic.save
        format.html { redirect_to community_topic_path[@community, @community_topic], notice: 'Community topic was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: [@community, @community_topic], status: :created, location: @community_topic }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @community_topic.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**views/community_topics/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for :community_topic, url: community_topic_index_url, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :community_id, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.number_field :community_id, :class => 'number_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :user_id, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.number_field :user_id, :class => 'number_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :title, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :title, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :body, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_area :body, :class => 'text_area' %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                community_topic_index_path, :class => 'btn' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**community_topics_controller.rb #show**

```
  def show
    @community = Community.find_by_community_name(params[:community_id])
    @community_topic = @community.community_topics

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @community_topic }
    end
  end
```

Comment: For `@community_topic = @community.community_topics.build (params[:id])` please show the Community model with the community_topic relationship.

Comment: thanks! in models/community.rb, has_many :community_topics. In models/community_topics.rb, belongs_to : community

Comment: You even need to show what is the rendered HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `communities_controller.rb`, try changing

```
    format.html { redirect_to community_topic_path[@community, @community_topic], notice: 'Community topic was successfully created.' }
```

to

```
    format.html { redirect_to community_topic_path(@community, @community_topic), notice: 'Community topic was successfully created.' }
```

Note the parentheses.

Does it work?

Comment: It looks almost working. now it says 'undefined method `model_name' for Array:Class' against  <%- model_class = @community_topic.class -%>.   Why it's not getting model_class by @community_topic.class. I think that's the problem why it won't show the record just created.

Answer (score 3):

Your rake routes are showing that the route is actually `community_topic`, since you used the `:as => 'topic'`.

Just call it as

```
community_topic_url
```

Comment: where should I put community_topic_url to????

Comment: @HUSTEN Use that instead of `community_community_topic_url`

Comment: @PabloFernandezheelhook It seems that I don't use community_community_topic_url  Where am I using it at?

Comment: You should add the backtrace you are getting so we can see where you are using it.

Comment: @PabloFernandezheelhook Thanks for reply!! How can I add the backtrace??? are you talking about log??

Comment: Yes, add the backtrace to the question.

Comment: @PabloFernandezheelhook I updated!! Added log, create action, and view